# Application is not installed

Tags: android

I test my application in android phone. it's a unsigned application export from eclipse.
When i installed the application in phone it's shows user permisson messages. then finally i got a message application not installed. here my mainfest code

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.z_enterprise.praywithme"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" 
    android:installLocation="preferExternal" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="2" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".about"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

             <activity
            android:name=".favour"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: If you don't sign an application, an Android device won't install it.

Comment: Thank you very much..i will accept all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Settings > Applications > Mark/Enable Unknown Sources

Mark answer, if useful